# Collapse/Expand animation for panel to edit

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a panel that shows a task. The tasks are being displayed by iterating through an array.

When a task is clicked, I want the panel **to expand and show a form which allows the user to edit the clicked task.**

How can I realize this behavior?

The panel has already an animation allocated to itself, namely a delete animation. How can I additionally add an expand/collapse animation - and **how do I make sure that the edit field is allocated to the task clicked.**

```
<div class="row content-cont" [@EnterLeave]="animation">
<div class="col-11 d-flex todo shadow-sm">

  <div class="row w-100 align-self-center">

    <div class="col-2 px-0 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-circle shadow-sm exceeded align-self-center" [ngClass]="'state' + task.state"
        (click)="updateState(task.id)"></button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-6 px-0">

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-6 d-flex">
            <h1 class="align-self-center">{{task.title}}</h1>
          </div>

          <div class="col-6 d-flex">
            <p class="desc align-self-center">{{task.describtion}}</p>
          </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row">
          <div class="col-4">
            <p *ngIf="task.date !== null">{{task.date | date: 'dd.MM.yyyy'}} 
            </p>
          </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-end">
        <img *ngIf="task.state !== '2'" class="align-self-center trash-button" src="/assets/icons/trash-2-colorized.svg" alt="Trash" (click)="deleteTask(task.id)">
        <img *ngIf="task.state === '2'" class="align-self-center" src="/assets/icons/trash-2.svg" alt="Trash">
    </div>
    <h1 class="priority position-absolute">{{task.priority}}</h1>

  </div>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: did you have a look at `<mat-expansion-panel>` ? https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

Comment: @Bobbey he's using bootstrap styles so that's probably a bad idea. Tim, what do you mean by "allocated to the task clicked"? What does `updateState` do?

Comment: just trying to figure out what he wants to see. in bootstrap the elements providing such behaviour are accordions, right?

Comment: @AluanHaddad It changes its state from 1-4.

Comment: Why not just pass the whole task and update its state. I don't see why it would get a reference to the wrong task regardless